# R geom_point draw points without data at the beginning of the chart. How can I remove them?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I am new to R.

I have a problem. I am trying to make a chart with 3 vars. One its the date called "Fecha", other its called kks1 and other its called kks2, these two are a time var.

The problem its when the chart its displaye. The chart shows me points out of the X axis, at the begin of the chart. I want to get out, but How to?

This is how looks:

[image]

and this is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)

kks <- read.csv("C:/Users/kks.csv",fileEncoding = "UTF-8", header = TRUE, sep = ",")


ggplot(kks, aes(y=Fecha)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = kks3, colour = "BAD"),size=5) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = kks2, colour = "GOOD") ,color="#0AB247",size=5)
```

And this is the csv:

```
Fecha,kks2,kks3
22/may,07:10:00,
23/may,11:05:00,08:30:00
24/may,07:23:00,
25/may,08:30:00,
26/may,09:23:00,
27/may,09:17:00,16:50:00
28/may,,12:00:00
29/may,,13:01:00
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: These are caused by the 'empty' values in your kks3 column. There's no value assigned to them, so ```ggplot2``` draws them outside of the range of the x-axis. The solution would be to have clean data.

Comment: I ran your code and didn't encounter those points, but I replaced 'empty' values with `NA`. Perhaps this helps you.

Comment: Yeah. Works! Thank you so much!